# Android- use image view as map and put marker at given x,y coord

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-mapview, android

I am a newbie in Android UI stuff. I tried looking for approach for going forward with this problem but could not get success, my apologies if this has been answered already.

I have a png image of a map, whose corner's points latitude and longitudes are known. Now given a lat long which lies inside the map, I want to put a marker on map for the given location say pointx. this requires two steps:
1. converting lat long to x,y for the pointx based on known point's x,y coordinates
2. drawing an image view for map and then putting the marker at the given x,y location

I can not use google maps here as the T&C doesn't allow. any pointers will be really helpful.